How to link to marker on Leaflet map from another URL
This works perfectly for activating a popup on a leaflet map on the same page:
{<a class="mplk" href="#where" onclick="t5.fire('click')">See on map</a>}.
The user is taken straight to the map, with the popup displayed.
How can it be adapted to activate the popup via a link from a different page?
I tried
{<a class="mplk" href="mappage.html#where"onclick="t5.fire('click')">See on map</a>} 
but it does not work. The user is taken to the anchor #where on mappage.html, but not to the map.
Any ideas?
